# show the dialpad with a given number in Blackberry 10 Cascades Beta 4 SDK

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I  am trying to figure out to show the dialpad with a given number in Blackberry 10 Cascades Beta 4 SDK.
Right now, I have this code:

```
bb::system::Phone::smileytongue:hone phone;
phone.requestDialpad(number, bb::system::Phone::LineType::Cellular);
```

Which causes this error: `Cannot open phone pps object`

So, I looked up about a pps object, and found [this page](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__ppsobject.html).

Is that what I need to use, if so how do I use it?  Or do I use something else, and how do I use that?
(I did by the way add `"LIBS += -lbb"` to my .pro file to be able to use a pps object, but that change alone did not fix it).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a phonepad with a certain number in Blackberry Cascades](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241050/how-to-show-a-phonepad-with-a-certain-number-in-blackberry-cascades)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've got "Access Phone" permission enabled in your `bar-descriptor.xml`

```
<permission>access_phone</permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in Qml page easily.....

---

Step 1: QML

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import bb.system.phone 1.0

Page {
    id: root

    Container {
             Button {
                    id: call
                    text: "Call Me"

                    onClicked: {
                                  phone.initiateCall(4563289)
                               }
                    }
              }

      }
```

---

Step 2: Add  in `LIBS += -lbb` .pro file

Step 3: Add `<permission>access_phone</permission>` in bar decriptor file